# GStreamer-Sharp - msg.type threw exception

Tags: c#, gstreamer, gstreamer-sharp

I'm trying to get GStreamer-Sharp to work on Windows.

I managed to get the videotestsrc to play through a videoauto sink and thought I'd cracked. So I started to build up some Bus Message handling when all of a sudden....

msg.Type = 'msg.Type' threw an exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException'

I'm at my wits end here... I've tried different binaries of GStreamer and X64/X32... I really would like to build this in C# rather than C or Python. Has anybody seen this before?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: 1. You should enable First Chance exceptions (if you are using Visual studio), to get more understanding of the problem. 2. You should check the static constructors.

Comment: Hi  Soundararajan, thank you for this! I have a new exception now and it looks like it's an issue with the dlls? If I'm running a x64 project, shouldn't it matter if there is a mix of 32 and 64 bit dlls? Thank you! Matt  System.BadImageFormatException
  HResult=0x8007000B
  Message=An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
  Source=gstreamer-sharp
  StackTrace:
   at Gst.Message.gstsharp_gst_message_get_type_offset()
   at Gst.Message..cctor()

Comment: Do you use unmanaged code in your C# project ? If that is the case then you need to build your project to align with the binaries you are using (either x86 / x64). Also make sure "prefer 32-bit" option is disabled in your project settings. (http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-45-and-visual-studio-11/)

Comment: Thanks Soundararajan, that must be where I went wrong. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you find that fixed the issue, please mark it as answer, so it's useful for others.

Comment: Do you want to post this as an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: Only if that fixed your issue :-), not for my credit

Comment: Yes, it was the cause of the issue. I also found a GitHub repo where somebody had compiled the DLL's in both X86 and X64 which was really helpful - https://github.com/stsundermann/libgstreamersharpglue. It's running now! So I'm happy :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody is having troubles getting DLL's for Gstreamer on Windows, please find the following [github repository](https://github.com/stsundermann/libgstreamersharpglue).

This allowed me to finally control Gstreamer through a windows appl